# How to change a line with sed using variables in a bash script

Tags: string, bash, variables, replace, sed

I have a script file that I am trying to make that will modify the command line parameters withing several start-up scripts.  This bash scrip will look for a path and replace the entire line with a new one.  Any help would be appreciated, below you will find an example of my code.

```
Path=/usr/bin/MyApplication
NewArguments= -a1 -b2 -c3
NewCommand="$Path $NewArguments"

sed -i 's,^'"$Path"'*,\'"$NewCommand"',' /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh
```

What I'm looking for is converting a line like this:

```
/usr/bin/MyApplication -x1 -y2 -z3
```

Into this:

```
/usr/bin/MyApplication -a1 -b2 -c3 &
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this:

```
sed -i 's,^'"$Path"','"$NewCommand"',' /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh
```

...which can be simplified as:

```
sed -i s,^"$Path","$NewCommand", /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh
```

...and probably easier to read as:

```
sed -i "s,^$Path,$NewCommand," /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh
```

Actually the way you assign `NewArguments` is also incorrect, and I would also improve the `sed`, so in finally your script could be written like this:

```
Path=/usr/bin/MyApplication
NewArguments='-a1 -b2 -c3'    
sed -i "s,^$Path.*,$Path $NewArguments \&," /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh
```

Comment: Your last suggestion works for the most part however it does not remove the old command line parameters.  For this to work properly I need to find the matching command, remove the old line and replace it with the new one.

Comment: The update does not seem to work ether.  Below you will find an what I am getting with your last updated option as well as what is expected.

**Previous Line:**
/usr/bin/MyApplication -x1 -y2 -z3

**The Resulting Line(using the update method):**
/usr/bin/MyApplication -a1 -b2 -c3 /usr/bin/MyApplication -x1 -y2 -z3

**Expected Line:**
/usr/bin/MyApplication -a1 -b2 -c3

Comment: @rutri it's not very readable here. Edit it into your question please.

Comment: The results have been edited into the question as asked.

Comment: @rutri I cleaned up my answer a little, but it's the same code as earlier. If you copy & paste correct it should work, if it still doesn't, I can't imagine why.

Comment: I figured out the problem, in my actual code I was adding an & character at the end which must be a reserved character.  I still in the & character in there so the scrip will start the application and finish.  The question now is how to escape the & character in the sed command line.

Comment: Easy, write like this: `\&`

Comment: That works, the final command was as follows `sed -i "s,^$Path.*,$Path $NewArguments \&," /root/etc/rc.d/99_start_app.sh`.  Thank you very much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

## double quotes to expand shell variables

```
sed "s/$var/$var2/" file
```